# Create RDD from RDD entry inside foreach loop

Tags: apache-spark

I have some custom logic that looks at elements in an RDD and would like to conditionally write to a TempView via the UNION approach using `foreach`, as per below:

```scala
rddX.foreach{ x => {      
    // Do something, some custom logic
    ...
    val y = create new RDD from this RDD element x  
    ...
    or something else   

    // UNION to TempView
    ...
}}
```

Something really basic that I do not get:

1. How can convert the nth entry (x) of the RDD to an RDD itself of length 1?
2. Or, convert the nth entry (x) directly to a DF?

I get all the set based cases, but here I want to append when I meet a condition immediately for the sake of simplicity. I.e. at the level of the item entry in the RDD.

Now, before getting a -1 as SO 41356419, I am only suggesting this as I have a specific use case and to mutate a TempView in SPARK SQL, I do need such an approach - at least that is my thinking. Not a typical SPARK USE CASE, but that is what we are / I am facing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: indeed at the risk of getting a -1 I see, I assume it just can't be done

Comment: Yeah, you cannot... And views are not really mutable. If you try to "mutate" with single item `UNIONS` it will just blow up in a few thousand iterations or so. From the description it sounds like use case for a real database. You could try to create table in Hive metastore, and apply changes using Hive CRUD operations with native client.

Comment: I am really pushing the boundaries here - I did it just like that in PL/SQL and then have been looking how I could do with driver / worker stuff. I keep on getting issues on inserting to Hive with foreach anyway, cannot insert into Hive, null pointer exception. Wondering if that would happen with a Jpure DBC connection. Looks like SCALA with JDBC is the better way. THX. Don't know why I got a -1, as it is valid question imho - for others

Comment: Maybe if you can explain the logic someone will figure out something better.

Comment: I have it all working on PL/SQL in the ORACLE DB as a prototype, it's quite hard to explain. It's about calculating for a set of records a new set of records which indicated date ranges and spread characteristics of that range. I can supply the logic via a notepad file and a gif, but not sure that works here and really I have solved it, just trying to fit in the driver / workers stuff. Trying zipwithindex now. It also has an element of sequentialness

Comment: Would something like loading table, repartitioning, and zipping partitions work?

Comment: My next port is mapPartitionswithindex, but that is for tomorrow, will post you as it is an interesting algorithm - I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you can't create RDD or DF inside `foreach()` of another RDD or DF/DS function. But you can get nth element from RDD and create new RDD with that single element.

EDIT:
The solution, however is much simplier:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Main {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val n = 534 // This is input value (index of the element we'ŗe interested in)

    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    // Creating dummy rdd
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(0 to 999).cache()
    val singletonRdd = rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(pair => pair._1 == n)
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was looking at that - but then got into the wrappedarray business. Code could well be of interest, just to check. i find this sort of thing unclear from the manuals and such though. Particularly with the support for a wide variety of computing models.

Comment: I've added the code. As you can see the function that you require is already implemented. :D

Comment: Will try that tonight, interesting to observe the difference, great stuff